# textFieldDidBeginEditing is called prematurely

Tags: ios, uitextfield, autoscroll, uitextfielddelegate

I have an application in which I have to scroll up in case of the keyboard showing.
to get the keyboard size, I'm registering the **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** event like so:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
     object:self.view.window]
```

This does work, the problem is, it is being called after the **textFieldDidBeginEditing** was called. So, I can't get the actual keyboard size, but only after the field is already in edit mode, which defeats the whole purpose of registering this event on the first place.
I'm sure I've called the **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** and not the **UIKeyboardDidShowNotification**, although switching these two yield the same results:
first call was made to the delegate method and only then to the notification method. Any idea on how to turn this around? Currently I'm hard coding the size, which is very bad practice...

Comment: Have you got solution for this?

Comment: I'm dealing with this issue too..

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that, when the keyboard notification fires, you need to know which UITextField is being edited, so that you can scroll correctly? If that's the case, then perhaps you could stash a reference to that UITextField in `textViewDidBeginEditing`, to be used when you receive the notification.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest a GitHub repository

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base class I have written for this use exactly.It is a subclass of `UIViewController`
Whenever I want to implement such behaviour I just make my view controller a sub class of this base class.

BTW - You are right. `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is called after keyboard shows up which is why you want to scroll up in the call backs method of the keyboard as described in my class.

Also please note that for this to work you need to embed your entire view in a Scroll View and connect the IBOutlet of the scroll view to it.

If you are not using story board remove the IBOutlet part and embed your view in a scroll view and make the connection in code.

After this said here is the code:

**Header File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BaseViewControllerWithKeyboard : BaseViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *activeField;

@end
```

**Implementation File**

```
#import "BaseViewControllerWithKeyboard.h"

@interface BaseViewControllerWithKeyboard ()

@end

@implementation BaseViewControllerWithKeyboard

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, _activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:_activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

@end
```

Comment: Please review this solution @Rizon

Comment: A use case that dodges this code... 1. if a UIView has multiple UITextFields and 2. only a subset of the fields need the view to be scrolled 3. then when a user moves the focus from one UITextfield to another, 4. keyboardWasShown: will not be called.

Comment: 1. Why will it not work with multiple textfields? It does 2. please explain 3. Son't see a problem in this case either. 4. KeyboardWasShown will get called if you registered to notification properly.

Comment: E.g., 1. user taps first UITextField and keyboardWasShown: is called. 2. keyboard is displayed and UIView is scrolled a little 3. user taps second UITextBox (let's say the keyboard overlaps the lower part of this box but the user can still tap it) 4. keyboard is visible and so keyboardWasShown: isn't called.

Comment: let's concentrate on #4. keyboardWasShown: doesn't get called when a user switches focus from one UITextField to another. Therefore it can move the view to better position the UITextField.

Comment: OK. I see. You are talking about a rear case where there is one text field which is slightly hidden by the keyboard. If you are concerned about this situation you can implement the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method and make arrangemnet there

Comment: I've no idea if this case is rare - it just happened to be my app's case where I'd laid out two UITextField vertically using Storyboard using its guidelines for spacing and bang - this was a case I had to deal with. Perhaps on a larger screen, eg iPad, where multiple boxes are visible at once, is a commoner case.

Comment: I added a handler for textFieldDidBeginEditing: which scrolls the controller's UIView if the keyboard is visible (a class bool) to make the textField visible. I needed to store the keyboard size as well (a class CGSize).

Answer (score 0):

I opened a new project in XCode 5, added a `UITextField` to the `ViewController` and connected its delegate.

This is my only code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myNotificationMethod:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)myNotificationMethod:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
    NSLog(@"Rect: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(keyboardFrameBeginRect));
}
```

Here's the log output:

**Portraid:**

```
 Rect: {{0, 480}, {320, 216}}
```

**Landscape:**

```
 Rect: {{-162, 0}, {162, 480}}
```

**Edit:**

Regarding `textFieldDidBeginEditing` being called before `name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, I don't really understand why there's a difference if the textField is in edit mode or not but there are a few ways to solve this.

1. saving a reference to textField from textFieldShouldBeginEditing and use it inside myNotificationMethod if in did textFieldShouldBeginEditing was triggered.
2. Playing around with `UIResponder` like so:

in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` -> Save a reference to the `UIResponder` and change the `UIResponder` to a temp irrelevant one. in `myNotificationMethod` do what ever you want to do to the textField (that is not in edit mode \ first responder), when you are done make it your main `UIResponder`.

Comment: That's cool, the thing is that if you'd use textfield:didBeginEditing: method you can see that it gets called before the keyboard notification is..

Comment: @Rizon What about saving a reference to `textField` from `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and use it inside `myNotificationMethod`  if in did `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` was triggered ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why there's a difference if the textField is in edit mode or not. A bit more explaining on why you'd want to do it may help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Apple documentation **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** is called just before the keyboard will be shown, while **UITextFieldDidBeginEditing** is called just after the text field becomes first responder. The process to show the keyboard is started **after** the text field becomes first responder, and only if the keyboard is not already shown. This means **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** will be called after **UITextFieldDidBeginEditing**. So **UITextFieldDidBeginEditing** is not called prematurely.

If you just want to scroll up so the text field won't be hidden under the keyboard, you can just set the content offset of the scroll view to the y-origin of the text field in **UITextFieldShouldBeginEditing** or **UITextFieldDidBeginEditing**.

Comment: "you can just set the content offset of the scroll view to the y-origin of the text field" The question is: how do you know if the UITextField needs the view's offset changing?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ran into the same issue today. I have built a little "dirty" workaround that does not force me to hardcode the keyboard size. I simply did the following in viewDidAppear (attention - Swift):

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.infoTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    self.infoTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

This triggers the **UIKeyboardWillShowNotification** and you can get the keyboard size from the notification and store it in a property. Hope this helps someone, it worked in my case.